# Creating wallets using apis

Tags: wallet, api

I am wondering whether the cardano block chain has the apis which i can integrate with a third arty cms. For example if i call an api the wallet has to be created and i can sent funds using the same wallet thinks like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

REST Api there is https://blockfrost.io/

Otherwise it´s the cardano-cli

Answer (score 1):

You create a wallet *(keys and addresses)* with just a few lines of code, eg like this: https://github.com/Emurgo/cardano-serialization-lib/blob/master/doc/getting-started/generating-keys.md. No need for remote services or interfacing w. the blockchain for this. Once you generate an address it's ready for you to use. Just create transactions using that address and submit those to the network *(eg using blockfrost)*. Whatever you send to an address will just be sitting there until the *key-holder* decides to spend it.

Comment: I need a remote service becose i am using a cms in which i have to give a wallet whenever a user is signing up.

Comment: ah okay sorry can't recommend any such service unfortunately. Must be one that you'd potentially trust access to all your funds to, though, if I understand correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can definitely use [cardano-wallet](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-wallet) but you will need local cardano-node's socket connection.
Once you are running it, it exposes REST APIs web services you can interact to